# using an absolute pointer address as a template argument

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I have a template class which takes as its first template argument a foo * pointer. I'd like to instantiate one of these with a foo located at an absolute address, like so:

```
class foo
{
    int baz;
};

template<foo *f> class bar
{
public:
    bar() {}
    void update() { /* ... */ }
};

// ....

#define FOO_ADDR ((foo *)0x80103400)
#define FOO_NULL ((foo *)0)

foo testFoo;

bar<FOO_ADDR> myFoo;        // fails with non-integral argument
bar<FOO_NULL> huh;          // compiles, I was surprised by this
bar<&testFoo> test;         // compiles as expected (but not useful)
```

Does anyone know if it's possible without resorting to the linker and getting FOO_ADDR to be defined with external linkage?

This is with the Keil ARM C/C++ Compiler version V5.06 update 1 (build 61), I've tried switching on C++11 mode but (apart from throwing a load of new errors in the system headers) it didn't change the behaviour.

Update: here's the proposed solution (with the real code this time) using int casts

```
template<uint32 PORT, uint32 BIT, uint32 RATE> class LedToggle
{
    uint32 mTicks;
    uint32 mSetReset;

    public:

    LedToggle()
    {
        mTicks = 0;
        mSetReset = 1 << BIT;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        uint32 mask = ((mTicks++ & RATE) - 1) >> 31;
        ((GPIO_TypeDef *)PORT)->BSRR = mSetReset & mask;
        mSetReset ^= ((1 << BIT) | (1 << (BIT + 16))) & mask;
    }
};

LedToggle<(uint32)GPIOC, 13, 1023> led;
```

It's pretty ugly, but it does work. I'd be interested to hear if anyone can improve on it?

Comment: FWIW, g++ fails at that line too.

Comment: It's defined in a system header as ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOC_BASE)

Comment: Hence the cast to uint32 in the template instantiation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declaration `bar<(foo*)0x80103400> myFoo;` is ill-formed because non-type template arguments must be a constant expression, from [temp.arg.nontype]:

> A *template-argument* for a non-type *template-parameter* shall be a converted constant expression (5.20) of the type of the *template-parameter*.

And the argument you are passing is not, from [expr.const]:

> A conditional-expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the
>   abstract machine (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>   — [...]
>   — a `reinterpret_cast` (5.2.10);
>   — [...]

The declaration `bar<(foo*)0> huh` works since it does not involve a cast, it's simply a null pointer of type `foo*` (`0` is special) and so it is a valid constant expression.

---

You could instead simply pass in the address as a template non-type parameter:

```
template <uintptr_t address>
struct bar { ... };

bar<0x8013400> myFooWorks;
```

That is viable.

Comment: You explain why it doesn't work, but provide no viable alternative solution.

Comment: @Barry, that proposed solution does not work for me in g++ 4.9.3. Perhaps it is valid in C++14.

Comment: Casting to/from ints does work, I was just hoping for something more elegant. Thanks all.

Comment: The original code compiles fine in Clang, fails in GCC. On the other hand, `constexpr foo* f = FOO_ADDR;` fails in Clang, compiles fine in GCC.

Comment: @Barry, I was testing with `template <foo* f> struct bar {};`.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper Original code fails in both. gcc is wrong for allowing initialization of `f` there.

Comment: @RSahu Sorry, was very unclear in what I meant by passing the address.

Comment: @Barry Doesn't seem to be the case for [Clang 3.8](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b609c998e458b53)

Comment: @sleeptightpupper That's a [bug in clang](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37305015/2069064).

Answer (score 5):

Facing the same problem (on an STM32), as a work-around I found function pointer template parameters, like so:

```
template<GPIO_TypeDef* PORT(), uint32 BIT, uint32 RATE>
class LedToggle
{
    public:

    void Update()
    {
        // ...
        PORT()->BSRR = mSetReset & mask;
        // ...
    }
};

constexpr GPIO_TypeDef* Port_C() {
  return PORTC;
}

LedToggle<Port_C, 13, 1023> led;
```

Notice that we use a *function* pointer as template parameter, to a function that returns the desired actual pointer. Inside that function casts are allowed; and since the function is declared `constexpr` the compiler may (should) optimize away the actual function call and use the function's return value like a literal.

Comment: Nice. Sadly I don't have `constexpr` but I like it.

Answer (score 3):

Casting to/from ints works, but as pointed out, it's dangerous. Another solution similar to JimmyB's is to use enum classes instead of function pointers. The enum class member values are set to the device addresses as specified inthe vendor-supplied header. For instance, for the STM32 series, ST provides a header with the following defined:

```
// Vendor-supplied device header file (example)

#define GPIOA_BASE = 0x40001000
#define GPIOB_BASE = 0x40002000
//    etc...
```

In your code, create an enum class:

```
#include <vendor-supplied-device-header.h>

enum class GPIO : uint32_t {
    A = GPIOA_BASE, 
    B = GPIOB_BASE, 
    C = GPIOC_BASE, 
    D = GPIOD_BASE, 
    E = GPIOE_BASE,
    F = GPIOF_BASE,
    G = GPIOG_BASE,
    #ifdef GPIOH_BASE   //optional: wrap each member in an #ifdef to improve portability
    H = GPIOH_BASE,
    #endif
    //.. etc
};
```

To avoid multiple messy casts, just do it once in the class using a private method. For example then your LedToggle class would be written like this:

```
template<GPIOPORT PORT, uint8_t PIN, uint32_t RATE> class LedToggle
{
    static_assert(PIN < 15, "Only pin numbers 0 - 15 are valid");

    volatile auto GPIOPort(GPIOPORT PORT) {
        return reinterpret_cast<GPIO_TypeDef *>(port_);
    }

    uint32_t mTicks;
    uint32_t mSetReset;

    public:

    LedToggle()
    {
        mTicks = 0;
        mSetReset = 1 << PIN;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        uint32 mask = ((mTicks++ & RATE) - 1) >> 31;
        GPIOPort(PORT)->BSRR = mSetReset & mask;
        mSetReset ^= ((1 << PIN) | (1 << (PIN + 16))) & mask;
    }
};

LedToggle<GPIO::C, 13, 1023> led;
```

The benefit of this method is that the class users are forced to use only members of the GPIO enum class, therefore invalid addresses are prohibited.

You can use enum classes for any of the template parameters, for instance you could replace the PIN parameter with an enum class whose members are set to the vendor's specified GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_2, etc. Then you'd write:

```
LedToggle<GPIO::C, Pin::_13, 1023>
```

Comment: I like this although sadly the compiler (Keil ARM C/C++ Compiler version V5.06 update 1 (build 61)) doesn't support enum classes

Answer (score 0):

Have you try casting the pointer address to and from `uintptr_t`, which is an unsigned integer capable of holding a pointer value?
The type is defined in a standard header `<cstdint>` but it is only optional. If it does not exist in your version of C++, try `size_t` instead.

A full example would then look like:

```
#include <cstdint>

class foo
{
    int baz;
};

template<uintptr_t addr> class bar
{
    constexpr static const foo* f = (foo*)(addr);
public:
    bar() {}
    void update() {  }
};

#define FOO_ADDR ((uintptr_t)0x80103400)

int main() {
    bar<FOO_ADDR> myFoo;
}
```

The obvious drawback is that there is no typechecking at the template parameter. You pass a value which will hopefully refer to `foo` object and not a different one.

Not to mention that we are in the undefined behavior world as far as the standard goes....

---

You seem to be able to compile with the line

```
constexpr static const foo* f = reinterpret_cast<foo*>(addr);
```

with at least some of the compilers as well (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5af62bedecf2d75a)

---

If your compiler rejects casting in the context of `constexpr` as it is ill-formed (as per Barry's comment) you can define it as a regular `static const` variable:

```
template<uintptr_t addr>
class bar
{
    static const foo* f;
public:
    bar() {}
    void update() {  }
};

template<uintptr_t addr>
const foo* bar<addr>::f = reinterpret_cast<foo*>(addr);
```

Less ideal but solves that problem hopefully.

Comment: I can make it work this way, but it's very grim. The address of foo is coming from a system header which has a (foo *) cast on it, so I have to explicitly cast it to a uint32 (or similar) and then back again in the template function. I was hoping to avoid this...

Comment: Initialization of `f` there is ill-formed for the same reason that passing in `FOO_ADDR` is ill-formed. gcc bug for allowing it (clang is correct in rejecting).

Comment: Doing anything with `f` with a hardcoded address is undefined behavior anyway. What matters is if OP can do it that way with *his* particular compiler.

Answer (score 0):

From the C++11 Standard (emphasis mine):

> **14.3.2 Template non-type arguments**
>
> 1 A *template-argument* for a non-type, non-template *template-parameter* shall be one of:
>
> — for a non-type *template-parameter* of integral or enumeration type, a converted constant expression (5.19) of the type of the *template-parameter*; or
>
> — the name of a non-type *template-parameter*; or
>
> — a constant expression (5.19) **that designates the address of an object with static storage duration and external or internal linkage** or a function with external or internal linkage, including function templates and function *template-ids* but excluding non-static class members, expressed (ignoring parentheses) as `&` *id-expression*, except that the `&` may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array and shall be omitted if the corresponding *template-parameter* is a reference; or
>
> — a constant expression that evaluates to a **null pointer value** (4.10); or

When compiled with `g++ -Wall`, I get the following error:

```
error: ‘2148545536u’ is not a valid template argument for ‘foo*’ because it is not the address of a variable
    bar<FOO_ADDR> myFoo;        // fails with non-integral argument
                       ^
```

It seems that the compiler is able to detect that `0x80103400` is *not* the address of a variable, it's just a constant expression.

Comment: For what it's worth, that section doesn't look like that anymore.

Comment: I see that it has changed a lot in C++14.

Comment: Reiterating my comment on other answer: "The original code compiles fine in Clang, fails in GCC. On the other hand, constexpr foo* f = FOO_ADDR; fails in Clang, compiles fine in GCC." I would refrain from making absolute statements "The compiler is able to detect that 0x80103400 is not the address of a variable".

Comment: @sleeptightpupper, that's the case for g++. It's unclear to me whether they are right in failing to compile that line of code.

Comment: @RSahu Considering the differing reasons between yours and Barry's answer and the inconsistent behavior in the two compilers I'm hesitant to make exact claims. Either way, OP added real code to his question. I doubt that OP "needs" to pass around the address of a port to templates.

Answer (score -2):

First, don't use c-style casts. It doesn't make it explicit what is does.

Second, you will realize that in order to cast an arbitrary number into a pointer, you need to use `reinterpret_cast`. This sort of cast is not allowed in constexpr expressions.

Since template parameters are only possible with constant expressions, an arbitrary number as a pointer is not possible.

The case where 0 is possible is because 0 is convertible to nullptr, which is constant expression.

Comment: You explain why it doesn't work, but provide no viable alternative solution.