# Reinterpret cast a template non-type parameter: clang c++14 vs c++1z

Tags: c++, clang, c++14, c++17

Consider the following code:

```
template <int* > struct foo { };

int main() {
    foo<(int*)42> f;
    (void)f;
}
```

When compiling on clang 3.8.0 with `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14`, the program compiles. When compiling with `-std=c++1z`, it errors with:

```
main.cpp:4:9: error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
    foo<(int*)42> f;
        ^~~~~~~~
```

gcc 5.3.0 does not compile the code regardless of C++ mode, which I believe to be correct. What is the difference in clang between C++14 and C++1z and why does it accept the code? Did something change in C++1z that is relevant here?

Comment: As a side note, VS 2015 compiles it just fine

Comment: Clearly a bug. C++1z relaxed constraints on non-type template arguments, so presumably a different code path (that doesn't trigger the bug) is used.

Comment: It's apparently treated like a null pointer: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/966a61826b6d73f9. This isn't sane behavior.

Comment: Does the standard make any guarantees about misaligned pointers in the first place? If it isn't legal to have an int at address 42, there's no reason to allow taking its address. (I saw something similar taking the addresses of members in a packed struct, but of course packed structs are an extension in the first place).

Comment: @T.C., what made you even think that was a possibility?

Comment: @Rakete1111 In what way is compiling the above code best described as "just fine".

Comment: @Yakk what I meant was that it compiles without errors, unrelated to the fact that the compiler may be wrong about it

Comment: @RSahu Asking clang what it thought `f`'s type is (also, checking how it mangles that type).

Comment: I may be completely off the mark..but I think for the C++11/14 case it's doing a [`CK_IntegralToPointer`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/deaa0006eedb4fa540726ef36cdd7c71853d6504/lib/AST/ExprConstant.cpp#L5038) cast, which explains the `nullptr` and for the C++1z case it's doing a [`CK_AddressSpaceConversion`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/deaa0006eedb4fa540726ef36cdd7c71853d6504/lib/AST/ExprConstant.cpp#L4998) cast.

Comment: [CheckTemplateArgument](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/9821058530c8aa4d14cfadb324194245032a1c91/lib/Sema/SemaTemplate.cpp#L4876) also suggests different behavior for C++1z and C++11, but I haven't gotten anywhere with that.

Answer (score 2):

Using [godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#) demonstrates that in `-std=c++1z` mode Clang 3.5.1 accepts the code but 3.6.0 rejects it. The [changelog](http://llvm.org/releases/3.6.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#id1) indicates that this version was when support for C++1z features were added, namely "Constant evaluation for all non-type template arguments". My guess is that C++11 and C++14 mode use the C++11 rules while C++1z mode uses the C++1z/latest draft rules. Of course, the fact that the program is considered valid in C++11/14 mode is a bug in of itself.

Here are some bug reports with similar (but not directly related) cases:

[Bug 18043 - allow arbitrary address constant expressions as non-type template arguments as an extension](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18043)

[Bug 10398 - Clang won't accept a null pointer constant as a non-type template argument](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=10398)

[Bug 10396 - clang crashes during name mangling with  as non-type template parameter](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=10396)

[Bug 9700 - Null pointer not accepted as non-type template argument](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=9700)